# Calling SubReport from MainReport using parameter

Tags: reporting-services, rdlc

I have a model which contains the following structure:

```
<Manifest>
  <Identifier>0</Identifier>
  <Headers>
    <Header>
      <AccountBarcode>635381834264679575</AccountBarcode>
      <SiteAddress1 />
      <SiteAddress2 />
      <SiteAddress3 />
      <SiteAddress4 />
      <SitePostcode />
      <SeriesNumber>Series 0</SeriesNumber>
      <CollectionDate>12/06/2014</CollectionDate>
    </Header>
  </Headers>
  <DomesticServices>
    <DomServices>
      <AccountNo>Dom Acc 0</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 0</Service>
      <NoOfItems>0</NoOfItems>
    </DomServices>
    <DomServices>
      <AccountNo>Dom Acc 1</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 1</Service>
      <NoOfItems>1</NoOfItems>
    </DomServices>
    <DomServices>
      <AccountNo>Dom Acc 2</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 2</Service>
      <NoOfItems>2</NoOfItems>
    </DomServices>
    <DomServices>
      <AccountNo>Dom Acc 3</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 3</Service>
      <NoOfItems>3</NoOfItems>
    </DomServices>
    <DomServices>
      <AccountNo>Dom Acc 4</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 4</Service>
      <NoOfItems>4</NoOfItems>
    </DomServices>
    <DomServices>
      <AccountNo>Dom Acc 5</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 5</Service>
      <NoOfItems>5</NoOfItems>
    </DomServices>
    <DomServices>
      <AccountNo>Dom Acc 6</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 6</Service>
      <NoOfItems>6</NoOfItems>
    </DomServices>
    <DomServices>
      <AccountNo>Dom Acc 7</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 7</Service>
      <NoOfItems>7</NoOfItems>
    </DomServices>
    <DomServices>
      <AccountNo>Dom Acc 8</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 8</Service>
      <NoOfItems>8</NoOfItems>
    </DomServices>
    <DomServices>
      <AccountNo>Dom Acc 9</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 9</Service>
      <NoOfItems>9</NoOfItems>
    </DomServices>
  </DomesticServices>
  <InternationalServices>
    <IntServices>
      <AccountNo>Int Acc 0</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 0</Service>
      <NoOfItems>0</NoOfItems>
    </IntServices>
    <IntServices>
      <AccountNo>Int Acc 1</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 1</Service>
      <NoOfItems>1</NoOfItems>
    </IntServices>
    <IntServices>
      <AccountNo>Int Acc 2</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 2</Service>
      <NoOfItems>2</NoOfItems>
    </IntServices>
    <IntServices>
      <AccountNo>Int Acc 3</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 3</Service>
      <NoOfItems>3</NoOfItems>
    </IntServices>
    <IntServices>
      <AccountNo>Int Acc 4</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 4</Service>
      <NoOfItems>4</NoOfItems>
    </IntServices>
    <IntServices>
      <AccountNo>Int Acc 5</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 5</Service>
      <NoOfItems>5</NoOfItems>
    </IntServices>
    <IntServices>
      <AccountNo>Int Acc 6</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 6</Service>
      <NoOfItems>6</NoOfItems>
    </IntServices>
    <IntServices>
      <AccountNo>Int Acc 7</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 7</Service>
      <NoOfItems>7</NoOfItems>
    </IntServices>
    <IntServices>
      <AccountNo>Int Acc 8</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 8</Service>
      <NoOfItems>8</NoOfItems>
    </IntServices>
    <IntServices>
      <AccountNo>Int Acc 9</AccountNo>
      <Service>Service 9</Service>
      <NoOfItems>9</NoOfItems>
    </IntServices>
  </InternationalServices>
  <TrackingRanges />
  <Footers />
</Manifest>
```

I have created datasets within my reports which are Manifests, Headers and Services so on.
This is a very simplified example but in my main report, I have a table which will display a subreport for each of the manifests.

Now I can pass the identifier in as a parameter but in my subreport, I have a table where the datasetname are Services, how do I tell it to load the service for manifest identifier sent by the parameter??

Thanks in advance!

Comment: It's not especially clear to me what you are trying to do, but couldn't you combine the Manifests and Services datasets into one.

Comment: The example I have given is a very simplified structure, the real one is quite a large structure.